# re-try logic in a simple loop

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to set bounds for an array that will later be printed in the console and summed. The lower bound ($a) should be less than 50 and I wrote this code to evaluate for that, but I want it to re-prompt for a number if a higher number is typed. So far, Google and experimentation have failed me.

```
def num_a
  print "Pick a number from 1 to 50: "
  $a = Integer(gets.chomp)
    until $a < 50
      puts "Um, try again please."
  # need something here to prompt for another response
  # until $a is less than 50
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could restructure the loop so that the prompt and call to `gets` are both inside it:

```
def num_a
  # start with a number that doesn't meet the condition
  a = 50

  # check if the number meets the condition yet
  until a < 50
    # ask the user to enter a number
    print "Pick a number from 1 to 50: "
    a = Integer(gets.chomp)
    # ask to try again if the number isn't under 50
    puts "Um, try again please." unless a < 50
  end

  # return the entered value to the caller
  a
end
```

Also, as I've shown in the example, I would recommend avoiding the use of global variables (`$a` in this case).

Comment: ah, thanks. I switched from local to global variables because when I encased the loop in method "num_a", the overall code stopped working (I call $a later on for the sum). maybe I don't need to though?

Comment: @jedgil Right, you shouldn't need to. Just assign the result of `num_a` to a variable where you need it, e.g. `value = num_a` and then use `value` as needed after that.

Comment: doh! makes perfect sense. I was using a hammer for a scalpel. thanks @neuronaut